# Trouble with Scanner input in Java

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm a student taking a Java programming class. My teacher asked us to use `JOption` pane to an exercise.  I think I have most of it but can't get it to work correctly.  My program isn't accepting  the choices put in the `JOption` panes but it accepts them in the CMD window.  The options are accepted after the `JOption` panes are cleared.  The code I have is:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Coffee10 {

    private static int item;
    private static double price;
    private static int menuNum;
    private static Scanner input;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        calculateP();

        if (menuNum > 0) //calculateP(); going for 3 instances of input
        {
            if (menuNum > 0) //calculateP();
            {
                if (menuNum > 0) {
                    calculateP();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public static double calculateP() {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Jivin' Java Coffee Shop" + "\nCoffee" + "\n(1)American     1.99" + "\n(2)Expresso      2.50" + "\n(3)Latte              2.15" + "\nMake selection. Press 0 to quit");
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Jivin' Java Coffee Shop" + "\nCoffee" + "\n(1)American     1.99" + "\n(2)Expresso      2.50" + "\n(3)Latte              2.15" + "\nMake selection. Press 0 to quit");
        JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Jivin' Java Coffee Shop" + "\nCoffee" + "\n(1)American     1.99" + "\n(2)Expresso      2.50" + "\n(3)Latte              2.15" + "\nMake selection. Press 0 to quit");
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Your total order comes to $" + price + ".");

        menuNum = input.nextInt();

        if (menuNum == 1) {
            item += 1;
            price += 1.99;
            return 1.99;
        } else if (menuNum == 2) {
            item += 1;
            price += 2.50;
            return 2.50;
        } else if (menuNum == 3) {
            item += 1;
            price += 2.15;
            return 2.15;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please format your code. It is unreadable.

Comment: What's going on with the commented out code (`calculateP()`)?

Comment: It was bringing up the JOption panes 3 times and only want it coming up 1 time.  Trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

You don't use a `Scanner` with a `JOptionPane.showInputDialog()`.  That method has a return value for the user input.  See [the javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showInputDialog-java.awt.Component-java.lang.Object-).

Answer (score 0):

You use `Scanner` on `System.in` witch is the standard input AKA Console, thats why it works for you when you use console. To get input from `JOptionPane` you have to store return value of `JOptionPane.showInputDialog` method. The return value of this method is user input

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get a value from JOptionPane you should use this:

```
String result = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Jivin' Java Coffee Shop" + "\nCoffee" + "\n(1)American     1.99" + "\n(2)Expresso      2.50"
                + "\n(3)Latte              2.15" + "\nMake selection. Press 0 to quit");
if(result != null){
menuNum = Integer.parseInt(result);
}
```